# Why is my <hr> element rendering differently on the same page?

Tags: html, css

I have a page that is an online version of an energy newsletter, and each story is separated by a `<hr>`. I just noticed today that one of them is rendering at 680px x 2px instead of 680 x 1px.

Having inspected the element I see the height comes from this css entry: "height: 0.1em;" and was wondering why the browser seems to think a different thickness is needed for this one and not the others? (I know it's not majorly important but it's just bugging me and someone must know!)

This is the page: http://utilitiessavings.co.uk/utilities-insider-issue-10-january-2013/

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An em is not an absolute unit of measure. It is proportional to your font size. Chances are, the two different `<hr>` tags are inheriting different font-sizes and are therefore calculating 0.1em differently.

Reference: http://kyleschaeffer.com/user-experience/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: The thing is, they all sit inside the same element. Font size is 13px.

Comment: I think I must have a rogue tag in there somewhere and wordpress is closing it for me maybe...

Comment: The point of the page I referenced is that when the font-size is also a relative measure, things can get a bit funky with how the em of the element in question is calculated.

Comment: Right, I see. That makes sense. I added a couple of extra `<hr>`s in to see what would happen and it seems the second one is always given the 2px height, so like you say it's just the browser being funky by the looks of it. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

As Eipark has suggested you are using em rather than pixels to format your HR bars.

Really simple fix would be

With Style.css look for line 67 hr { and change the follow below code from, too

From This

```
height: 0.1em;
```

To This

```
height:1px;
```

Comment: I understand that. I am just curious to learn more about em sizes as I don't know too much about them :)

Comment: I accepted this answer as it is what I actually did to fix it, but eipark's comments on using relative font sizes with other relative sizes are worth reading below.

Comment: Your question was why, not how to fix it. You should accept the answer that answers your question, primarily.